# How to avoid artifact lines when placing cubes next to each other to form a wall

Tags: 3d, three.js

I've been playing around with doing a little pathfinder using WebGL:

http://transfigure-game.github.io/app/

I am constructing walls by placing cubes next to each other. An artifact I am seeing is lines showing up at the cube boundaries. What's the best way to clean this up?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that normals of edges of the cube are shared by more than one face of the cube - so under light it appears as if it has rounded edges

To remedy this create the cubes from 6 distinct planes like this

```
side1 = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(this.environment.gridCellSize,this.environment.gridCellSize);
```

and rotate these 6 planes, then translate them by 1/2 of correct cube dimension in correct direction...

you will create cube with not 8 points but 24 so that each face of the cube has its own normals on the edge